# Tensorflow can't save custom model if it has dynamic variables (layers) created through vars(self)[...] = ... in __init__()

Tags: tensorflow

Python 3.8, Tensorflow 2.10.
I'm trying to create a custom model with a parametrized number of blocks each consisting of (CONV2D, BatchNorm, Activation) layers.

```
class CustomModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, repetitions, pool_size=2, strides=2):
        super(CustomModel, self).__init__()

        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.repetitions = repetitions
        self.rescaler = tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1 / 255.0)
        self.act = tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu')
        self.global_av = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='tanh')
        
        
        for i in range(self.repetitions):
            vars(self)[f'conv2D_{i}'] = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')
            vars(self)[f'batch_norm_{i}'] = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        
  
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.rescaler(inputs)

        for i in range(self.repetitions):
            x = vars(self)[f'conv2D_{i}'](x)
            x = vars(self)[f'batch_norm_{i}'](x)
            x = self.act(x)

        x = self.global_av(x)
        x = self.dense(x)
        
        return x
```

It trains without any errors, but if I try to save it (after training):

```
model.save('custom_model', save_format='tf')
```

the following error occurs:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[25], line 1
----> 1 model.save('custom_model', save_format='tf')

File ~\.conda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\.conda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function_saved_model_utils.py:160, in _raise_untracked_capture_error(function_name, capture, internal_capture, node_path)
    158 if internal_capture is not None:
    159   msg += f"\n\tInternal Tensor = {internal_capture}"
--> 160 raise AssertionError(msg)

AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references an 'untracked' resource. TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be 'tracked' by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly. See the information below:
    Function name = b'__inference_signature_wrapper_41604'
    Captured Tensor = <ResourceHandle(name="Resource-3-at-0x23702951070", device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", container="Anonymous", type="class tensorflow::Var", dtype and shapes : "[ DType enum: 1, Shape: [3,3,3,64] ]")>
    Trackable referencing this tensor = <tf.Variable 'custom_model/conv2d/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 64) dtype=float32>
    Internal Tensor = Tensor("41574:0", shape=(), dtype=resource)
```

Seems like the problem is with the dynamically created variables, like `vars(self)[f'conv2D_{i}'] = ...`. Is it allowed to initialize the instance attributes using `vars(self)`?